# Laravel's Concurrency Control

Tags: php, laravel, concurrency

I am designing a ticket purchase system using Laravel, and I was wondering how Laravel resolves concurrency - if at all (or is it all done in database?). Can concurrent transactions occur, and how does Laravel know they are taking place? I was looking at using this plugin called [Attendize](https://github.com/Attendize/Attendize) and using the plugin, I want to efficiently handle concurrent transactions. Any ideas?

Comment: Attendize says nothing about Concurrency Control.

Answer (score 0):

Databases provide support for transactions, which are groups of one or more queries that are grouped together in an "all-or-nothing" atomic operation.

What actually goes into a transaction must be defined by the application developer - the database does not know or care about your business domain.

I would expect that the developers of Attendize have encoded business rules relevant to ticket sales into their plugin (like making sure a rush of users cannot buy more tickets than are available due to synchronization failure).

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency can be resolved using [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues)